# Drawing a tetrahedron in WebGL

Tags: webgl

I am new for WebGL, I am trying to draw a very simple tetrahedron in WebGL.Something is going wrong somewhere. I am trying to use indices and trying to give color to each surface of the tetrahedron. But nothing except for background appears on the screen.

Following is the program that I have tried.

```js
function init1(){
  var canvas = document.getElementById("mycanvas");
  var gl = canvas.getContext("experimental-webgl"); 
  gl.viewport(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  gl.clearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1);
  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
  gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST); 

  var v = document.getElementById("vertex").firstChild.nodeValue;
  var f = document.getElementById("fragment").firstChild.nodeValue;

  var vs = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
  gl.shaderSource(vs, v);
  gl.compileShader(vs);

  var fs = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
  gl.shaderSource(fs, f);
  gl.compileShader(fs);

  var program = gl.createProgram();
  gl.attachShader(program, vs);
  gl.attachShader(program, fs);
  gl.linkProgram(program);

  var vertices = [
    0.0000, 0.0000, -1.0000 ,
    0.0000, 0.9428, 0.3333 ,
    -0.8165, -0.4714, 0.3333 ,
    0.8165, -0.4714, 0.3333 
  ]; 

  var indices = [ 
    1, 2, 3, 
    2, 3, 0,
    3, 0, 1,
    0, 1, 2
  ];

  var colors = [
    1.0,  1.0,  1.0,    // white
    1.0,  0.0,  0.0,    //  red
    0.0,  1.0,  0.0,    //  green
    0.0,  0.0,  1.0    // blue
  ];

  var itemDimension = 3;

  var cBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, cBuffer);
  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(colors), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
  program.vColor = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "vColor");
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(program.vColor);     
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(program.vColor, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0); 



  var vBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vBuffer);
  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
  program.aVertexPosition = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "aVertexPosition");
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(program.aVertexPosition);       
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(program.aVertexPosition, itemDimension, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

  var ibuffer = gl.createBuffer();
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ibuffer);                                       
  gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint16Array(indices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ibuffer);

  var numItems = vertices.length / itemDimension;

  gl.useProgram(program);   

  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
  gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, indices.length, gl.FLOAT, 0 );
}
init1();
```

```html
<script id="vertex" type="x-shader">

attribute vec3 aVertexPosition;
attribute vec3 vColor;
varying vec4 color;

void main() {
 gl_Position = vec4(aVertexPosition, 0.0, 1.0);
    color = vec4(vColor,1.0); 
}

</script>  
<script id="fragment" type="x-shader">

precision mediump float;
varying vec4 color; 

void main() {
   gl_FragColor = color;
}
</script>        

<canvas id="mycanvas" width="800" height="500"></canvas>
```

Comment: [You might find these articles helpful](http://webglfundamentals.org)

Comment: Thankyou gman :) Might be of help. I will certainly go through the tutorials :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you look at the JavaScript console?

I'm guessing if you did you would have seen errors.

Here's the JavaScript Console in Chrome

[image: javscript console chrome]

And here's the WebConsole in Firefox

[image]

The first errors are because your vertex shader didn't compile. You have

```
attribute vec3 aVertexPosition;
```

but

```
gl_Position = vec4(aVertexPosition, 0.0, 1.0);  // <=- ERROR!!!
```

You can't put a `vec3` into `vec4` with 2 more elements (5 elements total). The correct code is

```
gl_Position = vec4(aVertexPosition, 1.0);
```

The last error is because `gl.drawElements` has invalid arguments

```
gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, indices.length, gl.FLOAT, 0 );  // <=- ERROR!!
```

You can't have `gl.FLOAT` for type of indcies

You wanted

```
 gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, indices.length, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0 );
```

Here it is working

```js
function init1(){
  var canvas = document.getElementById("mycanvas");
  var gl = canvas.getContext("experimental-webgl"); 
  gl.viewport(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  gl.clearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1);
  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
  gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST); 

  var v = document.getElementById("vertex").text;
  var f = document.getElementById("fragment").text;

  var vs = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
  gl.shaderSource(vs, v);
  gl.compileShader(vs);

  var fs = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
  gl.shaderSource(fs, f);
  gl.compileShader(fs);

  var program = gl.createProgram();
  gl.attachShader(program, vs);
  gl.attachShader(program, fs);
  gl.linkProgram(program);

  var vertices = [
    0.0000, 0.0000, -1.0000 ,
    0.0000, 0.9428, 0.3333 ,
    -0.8165, -0.4714, 0.3333 ,
    0.8165, -0.4714, 0.3333 
  ]; 

  var indices = [ 
    1, 2, 3, 
    2, 3, 0,
    3, 0, 1,
    0, 1, 2
  ];

  var colors = [
    1.0,  1.0,  1.0,    // white
    1.0,  0.0,  0.0,    //  red
    0.0,  1.0,  0.0,    //  green
    0.0,  0.0,  1.0    // blue
  ];

  var itemDimension = 3;

  var cBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, cBuffer);
  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(colors), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
  program.vColor = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "vColor");
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(program.vColor);     
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(program.vColor, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0); 



  var vBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vBuffer);
  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
  program.aVertexPosition = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "aVertexPosition");
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(program.aVertexPosition);       
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(program.aVertexPosition, itemDimension, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

  var ibuffer = gl.createBuffer();
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ibuffer);                                       
  gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint16Array(indices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ibuffer);

  var numItems = vertices.length / itemDimension;

  gl.useProgram(program);   

  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
  gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, indices.length, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0 );
}
init1();
```

```html
<script id="vertex" type="x-shader">

attribute vec3 aVertexPosition;
attribute vec3 vColor;
varying vec4 color;

void main() {
 gl_Position = vec4(aVertexPosition, 1.0);
    color = vec4(vColor,1.0); 
}

</script>  
<script id="fragment" type="x-shader">

precision mediump float;
varying vec4 color; 

void main() {
   gl_FragColor = color;
}
</script>        

<canvas id="mycanvas" width="800" height="500"></canvas>
```

Comment: There is no error on the line. I think the arguments are mode, count, type, offset. I have entered accordingly. Does it needs to be something else?

Comment: @BhavyaArora type of the ***indices*** that is